# How to determine whether the application is a system application or not?

Tags: android, expandablelistview, android-package-managers

I want to determine whether a installed application is a system application or not.

So I have got a list of installed applications like this: 
[image]

And want to change the background colour of all applications, which are system applications.

Here is the corresponding part of my code:

```
private void kindElementTexte () {

    // TODO: Bildericons sollen angezeigt werden

    ActivityManager manager =
            ( ActivityManager ) this.getSystemService ( ACTIVITY_SERVICE );


    ArrayList< String > kinder = new ArrayList< String > ();


    final PackageManager pm = getPackageManager ();
    List< ApplicationInfo > packages = pm.getInstalledApplications ( PackageManager.GET_META_DATA );

    View inflate = getLayoutInflater(). inflate(R. layout. anwendung_starten_layout, null);


    String packetName = null;

    for ( ApplicationInfo packageInfo : packages ) {




        packetName = packageInfo.packageName;


        kinder.add ( packetName );
    }


    kindElemente.add ( kinder );


}
```

Is there a opportunity to do that?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

In the for-loop, check whether the app is a system app or not and adjust the color as needed.

You can check system apps with the following code:

```
for ( ApplicationInfo packageInfo : packages ) {
    if ((packageInfo.flags & ApplicationInfo.FLAG_SYSTEM) != 0) {
        //is system app
    }
}
```

Read more about different flags [in the ApplicationInfo documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/ApplicationInfo.html).

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a valid solution and displays all system apps for me:

```
for (ApplicationInfo packageInfo : packages) {
    if ((packageInfo.flags & ApplicationInfo.FLAG_SYSTEM) != 0) {
        System.out.println(packageInfo.packageName + "is a system application");
    }
}
```